# Running web project on HTTP Preview give error: "Could not find JRE executable" on MAC OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am trying to run Eclipse Mars on Mac. Java 8 is installed. (JDK and JRE)

Running web project on HTTP Preview gives error that Could not find JRE executable.

In **Eclipse>Prefrences>Java>Installed JREs** when I try to search the JRE in **/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Version** , I am not able to find any versions inside.

Any solution?

Comment: Newer JDKs are in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

Answer (score 2):

Given, that you installed Oracle Java (JDK) 8, open a *Terminal* and:

> sudo rm /Library/Java/Home

which removes old links first. Note: This step might be optional.

Second step  (Note: replace XX first!):

> sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_XX.jdk/Contents/Home /Library/Java/Home

This command recreates a symbolic link to the actual Java 8 installation folder.

Afterwards, a fresh installation of Eclipse should detect Java8 in your system and should work with this version out of the box. You can modify an installed Eclipse to use this installation by navigating in Eclipse to:
`Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`.

Finally, remove the old  JRE/JDK entries AND add a new one for the path (see above) with the name *Java8*.

Additionally, you can create or edit a file `.bash_profile` (in the directory of your user home) and put the following snippet there:

> export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

Save that file and reopen a *Terminal* instance. If you execute `export` as a command there, you should see a valid JAVA_HOME with the location of your JDK 8 installation. Restart your IDE afterwards.